# Seeking a naming convention for multiple Git repos under a single Team Project

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs

I'm an experienced developer, working solo and using VS 2015 together with on-premises TFS 2015. I'm just getting started with TFS, Git and Scrum, however, and so I have a lot to learn yet.

After some discussion with my project manager I've decided to organize everything I do (including even home-related non-software projects) under a single TFS Team Project (as discussed [here](http://nkdagility.com/one-team-project/) and [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2014/06/30/github-issues-saved-my-marriage/)).

I'm now trying to settle upon the best naming convention for my code repositories, as well as an appropriate storage folder hierarchy.

Initially I'm considering adopting a standard such as this, with a left-to-right narrowing scope:

```
work.customers.joespizza.posapp
work.customers.joespizza.hrmgr
work.customers.billthebarber.emptychaircounter
work.internal.products.whirlygigspinner
work.internal.products.nostrilfitter
work.internal.infrastructure.buildmanager
home.music.trumpetpractice.scoretransposer
home.household.toastercontroller
```

Source code storage would follow accordingly (e.g. `D:\Dev\Git\Work\Customers\JoesPizza\PosApp`).

I have two questions:

1. Does this seem like a sound approach, at least to get things started?
2. Assuming I do go with this, is the TFS/VS/Git combination flexible enough to allow for a later restructuring, should it eventually prove to be troublesome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"restructuring"

If each of your folders is it own repo, that repo root folder can be renamed / moved any way you want, it won't change anything for its content: the git repo will remain unchanged.
(note: [you can create multiple git repo for one TFS project](https://www.benday.com/2014/05/23/yes-can-create-two-git-repos-per-tfs-team-project/), also [detailed here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2014/11/19/many-git-repositories-but-one-team-project-to-rule-them-all.aspx))

If, by "restructuring", you mean split a git repo in two, then that is harder, and would involve [splitting a repo in two](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/split-a-repository-in-two-313464964.html), and import them in Visual Studio separately.

Comment: Very good, thank you. That's a relief. What do you think about #1? (I'll have to be more careful in the future about multiple sub-questions within a main question.)

Comment: @InteXX #1 looks good. You will see over time if some of those repos need to be regrouped or can stay on their own.